# Use the bash autocomplete with [TAB] from within a script where the input is in a variable

Tags: bash, shell, bash-completion

I have a bash script that asks the user for them to type in a file name.  I want the script to accept partial file name such as /b, and the script should output a list of files that includes every file that matches that partial name.  For Example:

there are files named
`animal`
`bat`
`boo`
`bury`
in `/`

typing `/b` should then result in `bat boo bury`.  If a user enters `/animal/c` the program should result in all files starting with a c in the animal folder.

Essentially I am trying to get the effect of [TAB] with a static input inside a script.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use tab completion. Use globs. `/b*` will match `/bat`, `/boo` and `/bury` if these files or directories exist.

```
#!/bin/bash 
shopt -s nullglob
IFS= read -p "Enter a full or partial name: " -r filename
for f in "$filename"*
do
    echo "Possible match: $f" 
done
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of this, I had used this type of thing before, but I didn't think of it in this applications.  Thanks